# Can Ministry officials Apparate inside Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, fantastic-beasts, apparition

In the recently launched trailer of *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald*, there are people Apparating inside Hogwarts grounds.

As these people later question Professor Dumbledore, it seemed they were Ministry officials.

Have we ever encountered such Apparition before? Or, was this anti-Apparation charm put into place in recent times?

Comment: In the Order of the Phoenix and The Half Blood Prince, good old Albus apparated within the school (which was possible because the enchantments were lifted by him for a short time). I guess it's the same in the new movie.

Comment: I don't think the bridge counts as being inside Hogwarts grounds.  Presumably, that's why they apparated there rather than directly to where they're going.

Comment: @Shreedhar - When did he do that? I don't ever remember that. He travels by broom, fawkes, floo, and portkey, but never by apparation.

Comment: @ibid In the HBP film they Apparate straight to the Astronomy tower rather than into Hogsmeade.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - So then is likely more of that movie nonsense.

Comment: @ibid Perhaps. Or perhaps not. Dumbledore has the power to lift the anti-Apparition jinx for the Great Hall—why shouldn’t he also have the power to exempt himself from it? (Officials Apparating on to the bridge sounds a lot more like film nonsense to me—the books make it clear that it’s the entire grounds, forest, lake and all—but then nearly everything in FB seems to be nonsense.)

Comment: @Janus, the bridge doesn't even exist in the books, does it?

Comment: @HarryJohnston There’s no mention of a bridge at Hogwarts in the books. There’s a suspension bridge, the Brockdale bridge that the Death Eaters destroy, and Dolores Um-bridge. :P

Comment: It may be done quite simply to add to the intrigue. The "Can't apparate inside Hogwarts" thing is pushed quite heavily in the harry potter series yet the first thing you see in this trailer is just that thing happening.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - But even then they only apparate within the Great Hall. They don't enter or leave Hogwarts.

Comment: @ibid We don’t know if they’d be able to or not. The general rule is that you cannot Apparate anywhere within the Hogwarts grounds, neither as origin nor as destination. We do know that when the jinx is lifted in the Great Hall, it can be used as both origin and destination, just not what the limitations on the ‘other end’ are (or aren’t). Whether lifting the jinx temporarily means that the Great Hall becomes regular Apparition space or that it becomes its own little closed space where you can Apparate within it, but not to or from it—that we just don’t know.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Once Harry didn't get permission to go to Hogsmeade. At that time, Harry and Lupin walked on that bridge (when Lupin told Harry that he had her mother's eyes). So, I believe that bridge is inside the Hogwarts grounds because Harry didn't have permission to leave the campus.

Comment: @WhiteWidow, to clarify, I assume that happened in the movie version of *Prisoner of Azkaban*?  I'd have to see the scene - did they actually reach the far side of the bridge?  That could easily be a continuity error, one set of scriptwriters thought the bridge was on the grounds and another set thought it was on the border.  (For an in-universe excuse, perhaps the grounds were expanded at some point in the intervening decades?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The Rules of Apparition at Hogwarts

#### Anti-Apparition Charms are as old as Hogwarts

> Some rode broomsticks (a difficult feat when carrying trunks and
> pets); others commandeered enchanted carts and, later, carriages; some
> attempted to Apparate (often with disastrous effects, as **the castle
> and grounds have always been protected with Anti-Apparition Charms**),
> others rode a variety of magical creatures.
>
> **Source**: [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-hogwarts-express); The Hogwarts Express

#### Hermione about the Jinxes

Harry Potter and The Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 4

> Dumbledore said to Harry:
>
> "In any case, most Wizarding dwellings are magically protected from
> unwanted Apparators. At Hogwarts, for instance —"
>
> "— **you can’t Apparate anywhere inside the buildings or grounds,**" said
> Harry quickly. "Hermione Granger told me."
>
> <sub><sub>Harry Potter and The Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 4</sub></sub>

#### Jinxes lifted for Apparition learning

We know that the jinxes were removed to allow some Apparition training in the Great Hall. That happened in HP 6.

### Movie possibilities

So how does it come, that they can Apparate in the movie trailer at Hogwarts grounds?

1. The filmmakers don't care enough
2. The bridge isn't part of the jinxed grounds
3. The jinxes were temporarily removed
4. They don't Apparate / use different magic to Apparate (Dobby and others are able to Apparate; and Dumbledore can, using "portus", teleport at Hogwarts as well)

Answer (score 19):

#### No Ministry official actually Apparates into Hogwarts or Disapparates from Hogwarts in the movie.

In “Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald, Ministry officials do go to see Dumbledore at Hogwarts, but they entered through the door, not by Apparition.

> “*The class laughs. The door opens. TRAVERS, THESEUS, and four other AURORS enter, YOUNG MINERVA MCGONAGALL behind them.*
>
> **MCGONAGALL**
>
> This is a school, you’ve no right—
>
> **TRAVERS**
>
> I’m the Head of Magical Law Enforcement and I have the right to go wherever I please.
>
> *(to the students)*
>
> Out of here.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald*</sup></sub>

They also all leave through the door, they don’t Disapparate.

> “**TRAVERS**
>
> From now on, I shall know every spell you cast. I’m doubling the watch on you, and you will no longer teach Defense Against the Dark Arts.
>
> *(to THESEUS)*
>
> Where’s Leta? We need to go to Paris!
>
> *He storms out. The AURORS follow. THESEUS is last to the door.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald*</sup></sub>

So no instances of Ministry workers either Apparating into or Disapparating from Hogwarts are seen in the movie.

---

***Answer as written before the release of “Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald”.***

#### Ministry workers aren’t *said* to be able to Apparate at Hogwarts.

There’s nothing in either the books or movies that says that Ministry officials are able to Apparate onto Hogwarts grounds. It may be said in the new movie that the Ministry of Magic has the power to bypass protection from Apparition. However, in both the books and movies, we never see a Ministry official do it, even when they’re “opposing” Hogwarts.

#### The protection against Apparition might not extend to the bridge.

When Snape tries to escape from Hogwarts after carrying out his promise to Dumbledore that he’d kill him, Harry tried to stop Snape and Draco from reaching the gates, because once they get past the gates they’ll be able to Apparate.

> “And now he saw the vast outline of Hagrid, illuminated by the light of the crescent moon revealed suddenly from behind clouds; the blond Death Eater was aiming curse after curse at the gamekeeper, but Hagrid’s immense strength, and the toughened skin he had inherited from his giantess mother, seemed to be protecting him; Snape and Malfoy, however, were still running; they would soon be beyond the gates, able to Disapparate –” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 28 (Flight of the Prince)*</sup></sub>

It’s possible if the bridge is outside the main part of the Hogwarts grounds, that the protection doesn’t encompass the bridge, so they could Apparate onto the bridge and walk the rest of the way.

[image: The bridge and the Ministry officials]

From just looking at the bridge (both me and two close friends looked at it), it seems like it could be an “entryway” bridge.

The virtual Hogwarts on Pottermore (available to anyone with an account has a bridge that matches the one in the trailer as the entrance.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the virtual Hogwarts on Pottermore is just supposed to be the 3d model directly imported from the movie. I don't think it's meant to convey any additional information about Hogwarts.

Comment: Well, this question is about the new *Fantastic Beasts* movie, so it makes sense they’d use the same model - and on it they show the bridge as the entrance.

Answer (score 11):

In Harry Potter timeline, Apparition in and out of Hogwarts is blocked by a spell maintained by the current Headmaster (Dumbledore).

<sup>**Harry Potter and The Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 4**</sup>

> *(Dumbledore to Harry)*:
>
> “ In any case, most
>   Wizarding dwellings are magically protected from unwanted Apparators. At Hogwarts, for instance
>   —”
>
> “— **you can’t Apparate anywhere inside the buildings or grounds**,” said Harry quickly.
>   “Hermione Granger told me.”

Apparently, Hermione Granger had read it in "*Hogwarts: The History*".

In Book 6 (Half-Blood Prince) it is temporarily lifted for students to practice Apparition.

As for your example:

- The apparition ban could probably be not in force yet, although I doubt it
- If the officials were expected, it could be temporarily lifted
- As Harry Johnston noted in comment, the bridge may be not exactly Hogwarts grounds. In the quoted example, you may apparate by a wizard's door, then knock. It is not the same as apparating inside his house.

Comment: It could also just be another movie goof.

Comment: _Hogwarts: **The** History_? Bathilda would be disappointed!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Bathilda might actually be quite amused! As the author of *A History of Magic*, she might like seeing someone get the competition’s name wrong!

Comment: @Bellatrix How do you mean? She wrote both books, did she not?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet No, she’s only known to be the author of *A History of Magic*. The author of *Hogwarts: A History* is unknown - but it’s probably not Bathilda since in Deathly Hallows, she’s only mentioned as the author of *A History of Magic*, including by Hermione.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - We actually have [a question about that](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170627/who-wrote-hogwarts-a-history). The answer is as Bellatrix just said, its authorship is unknown, but most probably *not* Bathilda Bagshot.

Comment: @ibid Yeah, I saw that question after Bellatrix’ comment.

Answer (score 4):

### Perhaps the officials were using some sort of beast.

Here's a possibility that no-one seems to have mentioned: There's a known loophole to the anti-apparation law. House-elves CAN apparate in and out of Hogwarts. Presumably other animals can do so as well. In fact we see Fawkes doing something similar in OOP:

> Fawkes circled the office and swooped low over him. Dumbledore
>   released Harry, raised his hand, and grasped the phoenix’s long golden
>   tail. There was a flash of fire and the pair of them had gone.

Considering the film is titled 'Fantastic Beasts', I don't believe it too farfetched to consider they used this loophole.

Answer (score -1):

Given that the film is set in the past, it is possible that the anti-Apparition spell hasn't yet been applied to Hogwarts. Possibly something in the film happens that creates a need for such a spell (like this).

Comment: One of the other answers contains a quote from J.K. Rowling that "the castle and grounds have *always* been protected with Anti-Apparition Charms". Doesn't sound like it's something new.